# Best Ingress Controller in AWS EKS for millions of connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

We need a guide on how we can operate millions of connections with Nginx Ingress Controllers. Now, while load testing more than 10,000 users, it says 502 gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Istio** with  **ALB** (Application Load Balancer ) in a multi AZ approch
And if you will receive a million of request, you can contact AWS support to prewarm the Load Balancer

The other benefits of using ALB with istio, is the application of WAF + custom SSL domain

```
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    # create AWS Application LoadBalancer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    # external type
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    # AWS Certificate Manager certificate's ARN
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:***:certificate/****"
    # open ports 80 and 443 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    # redirect all HTTP to HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
```